I need to divide the page into 4 parts in latex. How to divide that?
I need a format like the below image
I searched for this in google and only i got the code for dividing into 2 coulmns but i need to divide in 4 columns so that i can add my skills specific to that. Please help me in providing the code. Thank you in advance...

Please help the people, who you expect to spend their free time on your problem, by providing a compilable [mre].

I think it probably works in latex. Try this code below
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Large\textbf{Skills}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{itemize}[label=,leftmargin=*]
    \item Programming
        \begin{itemize}[label=--,leftmargin=*]
            \item Java
            \item Python
            \item C++
            \item JavaScript
        \end{itemize}
    \item Web Development
        \begin{itemize}[label=--,leftmargin=*]
            \item HTML/CSS
            \item JavaScript Frameworks (React, Angular)
            \item Backend Technologies (Node.js, Express)
            \item Database Management (MySQL, MongoDB)
        \end{itemize}
    \item Data Analysis
        \begin{itemize}[label=--,leftmargin=*]
            \item Data Cleaning
            \item Statistical Analysis
            \item Data Visualization (Matplotlib, Seaborn)
            \item Machine Learning (Scikit-learn, TensorFlow)
        \end{itemize}
    \item Design
        \begin{itemize}[label=--,leftmargin=*]
            \item Adobe Photoshop
            \item Adobe Illustrator
            \item Figma
            \item Sketch
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}

Don't need to include header files if you need to want page slicing in the middle or end of the page.
